# Prompting for a positive integer and validating user input in Java

Tags: java, beginner, validation, io

I'm just starting out with Java, and trying to make a method to get a positive integer input from the console. My currently working implementation is this:

```
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int getPositiveIntInput(String message) {

    int n;

    String error_message = "Error: input must be a positive integer.";

    System.out.print(message);
    while (true) { // This is often frowned upon?

        // Check that input is integer
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.print(error_message + "\n" + message); // Gets repeated
            sc.next();

        }

        n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        // Check that input is positive
        if (n > 0) {

            return n;

        } else {

            System.out.print(error_message + "\n" + message);

        }
    }

}
```

In order to make my code more readable and concise, I attempted to rid myself of the `while (true)` and several error message prints by combining the integer and positivity checks into one loop, but I'm not getting the behaviour I would expect:

> ```
> public static int getPositiveIntInput(String message) {
>
>     String error_message = "Error: input must be a positive integer.";
>
>     System.out.print(message);
>
>     // Check that input is integer and positive
>     while (!sc.hasNextInt() || sc.nextInt() <= 0) {
>
>         System.out.print(error_message + "\n" + message);
>         sc.next();
>
>     }
>
>     int n = sc.nextInt();
>     sc.nextLine();
>
>     return n;
>
> }
> ```

---

What would be an effective way of improving the readability and reducing repetition while achieving the same functionality as in my original implementation? Particularly regarding the `while(true)` loop - I've seen it's use being discouraged in other SO threads. Would this be a case where a different looping structure could/should be considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> while (true) { // This is often frowned upon?
> ```

Frowned upon? Not that I know of.

Using a scanner for extracting numbers or tokens from a stream of input is great when the data is guaranteed to be in the expected format, and when it's ok to crash on any error.

The `.nextInt` and similar methods are less practical when you have to validate the input and give a chance to retry. In such cases I find it a lot more practical to read line by line, and perform the integer parsing manually, like this:

```
public static int getPositiveIntInput(String message) {    
    System.out.print(message);

    while (true) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (n > 0) {
                return n;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // ok to ignore: let it fall through to print error message and try next line
        }
        System.out.print("Error: input must be a positive integer.\n" + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps "often frowned upon" was an overstatement - after some light browsing on the topic I just came upon SO questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850380/are-whiletrue-loops-so-bad) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-whiletrue-bad-programming-practice) where the use of `while(true)` was discouraged by several commentors. I like the try-catch approach here - seems a lot less error prone than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me review your current working code. There is really not much I could improve: I find your code very readable and clear. Still, a couple of comments

1. You should try to respect the Java naming conventions. In this case the variable `error_message` should be named `errorMessage`: camel-case is preferred.
2. Try to always declare the variables when they are needed. In this case, the `int n` at the start of the method can be moved further down so that you have

   ```
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   // rest of code
   ```
3. If you input something with a space, you will have a slightly incorrect output (the error message will be printed as many times as there are spaces). This is because you are calling `sc.next();` to ignore it when you should be calling `sc.nextLine();`. `next()` returns the next token and tokens are space-separated by default.

---

Your attempt is really close. You could have the following:

```
public static int getPositiveIntInput(String message) {
    int n;
    String errorMessage = "Error: input must be a positive integer.";
    System.out.print(message);
    while (!sc.hasNextInt() || (n = sc.nextInt()) <= 0) {
        System.out.print(errorMessage + "\n" + message);
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    return n;
}
```

What this does is that it enter the `while` loop to display the error message when either the next token  of the scanner isn't an `int` or the returned value of `nextInt()` isn't strictly positive. The trick here is to store the result of call directly in the `while` expression.

If this is better, I'm not sure though... :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! Especially the assignment inside the condition - I wasn't aware that was possible.